# ConnectionString retornando null

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, visual-studio, connectionstring

Ao tentar executar meu projeto é me retornado o erro:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Referência de objeto não definida para
>   uma instância de um objeto.'

Possuo uma classe de banco com o construtor:

```
public bd()
{
    conexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conexaoBD"].ConnectionString);
    conexao.Open();
}
```

Estou usando o Visual Studio 2017, alguem pode me ajudar nesse erro?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: App.config? Isso esta na camada do seu asp.net? Veja se seu App.config esta como Embedded resource indo nas **Properties** -> **Build Actions**

Comment: está na camada de repositório

Comment: arquivos .config serve para configurar um executável, não é interessante possuir ele em uma camada de biblioteca, como a de um repositório. Sua string de conexão deve existir dentro da camada que o executável existe. Tente colocar sua connectionstring dentro do seu web.config

Comment: Mesmo na camada de asp.net retorna o mesmo erro...

Comment: Muito obrigado Gabriel, era isso mesmo, ele tem que ficar dentro do web.config, é que estava vendo uma video aula só que a pessoa colocou dentro do app.config mas era um projeto console. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: @Desalex talvez lhe interesse: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sua `connectionstring` deve existir dentro do projeto que possui o executável, no caso do asp.net deve existir dentro do web.config ou outro arquivo .config que seja referenciado pelo web.config.

No seu caso o problema era que, ao instalar o pacote do Entity Framework, o mesmo criou um app.config na camada e você estava tentando configurar ele neste local.